# V-rep IndexError

Tags: python, numpy

I'm following a v-rep tutorial using remote api and a get the error "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0", i now more or less what the error is but couldn't correct it,
the code:

```
while (time.time()-t) < 60000:
    sensor_val=np.array([])
    for x in range(1, 16+1):
        #if x == 1 or x == 5 or x == 8:
            errorCode, detectionState, detectedPoint, detectedObjectHandle, detectedSurfaceNormalVector = sim.simxReadProximitySensor(clientID, sensor_h[x-1], sim.simx_opmode_buffer)                
            sensor_val = np.append(sensor_val, np.linalg.norm(detectedPoint))
            
            
            sensor_sq=sensor_val[0:8]*sensor_val[0:8]
            
            min_ind = np.where(sensor_sq == np.min(sensor_sq))
            min_ind = min_ind[0][0]
```

The error is happening here:

```
min_ind = min_ind[0][0]
```

The tutorial say that this line is to transform de np array in a simple number
and the code work, sometimes for 10 seconds, sometimes for 20, but in the end i got the error, can anyone explain to me what i should do.

Comment: That tutorial shouldn't be using `np.append`.  List append is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look on your `sensor_sq` when it happens.

This can happen when your `sensor_sq` has `np.Nan`. I suspect this is what happens to you.

Because in numpy `np.NaN == np.NaN` is False, the `np.where()` returns `(array([], dtype=int64),)` which fails on the second `[0]`.

You need to handle this specific use-case by checking that your `sensor_sq` does not contais NaNs.

for example by:

`if np.isnan(sensor_sq).any():`
or by checking that the `if not np.isnan(np.min(sensor_sq)):`

Comment: I looked and there is at least one value with NaN in sensor_sq, so i used `if not np.isnan(np.min(sensor_sq)):`, and worked thank you.